# Countdown speeds up when the button that starts it is pressed multiple times

Tags: swift

I just started to learn swift . and I found when using a button to start a count down if i pressed the button twice it speeds up the process. What to add to prevent that?

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(processTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
@objc func processTime(){
        if counter > 0 {
            counter -= 1
            timeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        }else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }

    }
```

---

I tried to use `sender.isEnabled = false` it gave this error (Value of type 'Any' has no member 'isEnabled')
so I did it like this :

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if timer.isValid != true{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(processTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You could check to see if the `Timer` has been initialised previously or not (ie `!= nil`), but that would assume that when you're done with the timer, you're setting it to `nil`

Comment: You should never use a timer to measure time. Just store the start Date when starting the counter and use the timer only to update the user interface `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways, depends on what logic you prefer.
Basically you need to ensure that the `timer` starts only once until it completes.

In the following example, we start the `timer` only if it's not been initialized previously.
Furthermore, when we stop the `timer`, we explicitly set it to `nil` so the following logic works again after the timer completes.

```
//globally declared as optional
var timer: Timer?

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //check if timer is nil
    if timer != nil {
        //start timer only if timer is nil
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, 
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(processTime), 
                                     userInfo: nil, 
                                     repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func processTime() {
    if counter > 0 {
        counter -= 1
        timeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    }
    else {
        timer.invalidate()
        //clear the timer
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `sender.isEnabled = false` and after you press the button once it won't be clickable again

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate the timer by calling `timer.invalidate()` before you reassign a new timer. If you assign a new timer instance to the old one without invalidating, you will lose reference to it and it will never be invalidated.

Comment: [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and use formatting